# Executing server side code (node.js) on click of a button from within an HTML page generated through Jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to develop a web application and I am stuck at a point where I need some server side code to be executed on click of a button (through the onClick event handler and not the Submit button. I learnt how to route traffic that way through a form action). I am using Node.js, Express and Jade.
Can someone please help me. Here is my current code snapshot

I have made the following changes with respect to app.js to route the on-click traffic to this node.js function

```
app.post('/overview/delete-uni', uniappController.deleteUniversity);
```

Within the appropriate controller file I have added the deletion code

```
exports.deleteUniversity = function(req, res) {
  // Code logic
  // More code logic
  res.render('uniapp/university', {
  title: 'University'
  });
```

};

My Jade Template looks like this. Here when I click the `Update` button I need the `deleteUniversity` code to be executed

```
extends ../layout

block content

  .mdl-layout.mdl-js-layout.mdl-color--grey-100
      main.mdl-layout__content
        .mdl-grid
          #user
          for application in user.applications
            form.form-card.form-horizontal(action='/overview/update-uni', method='POST')
              input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=_csrf)
              .mdl-card.mdl-shadow--2dp                    
                .mdl-card__supporting-text
                  textarea#sample5.mdl-textfield__input(type='text', rows='1', name='universityName', readonly)
                    if application.university.name
                      | #{application.university.name}
                  .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label
                    textarea#sample5.mdl-textfield__input(type='text', rows='1', name='universityDescription')
                      if application.university.description
                        | #{application.university.description}
                    label.mdl-textfield__label(for='sample5') Description of university...
                .mdl-card__actions.mdl-card--border
                  button.mdl-button.mdl-button--colored.mdl-js-button.mdl-js-ripple-effect(type='submit')
                    | Update
                .mdl-card__menu
                  button.mdl-button.mdl-button--icon.mdl-js-button.mdl-js-ripple-effect
                    i.material-icons delete
```

P.S : I am a complete noob w.r.t Jade and hence please forgive me if this is something trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript file deleteUni.js (or whatever you want to call it) and add this to your template script(src="/Scripts/deleteUni.js")

```
//content of name.js
$(function(){

    var isButtonDisabled = false;
    $('#buttonId').click(function($event){

        //this part handles multiple button clicks by the user, trust me on this one, it's really important to have it
        if (isButtonDisabled){
            return $event.preventDefault();
        }
        isButtonDisabled = true;

        var formData = $('#formId').serialize(); //serialize form to a variable

        $.post( "/overview/delete-uni",formData)
         .success(function(response){
            //handle response

         })
         .fail(function(error){
            //handle error
         })
         .always(function(){
            //always execute
            .
            .
            .
            isButtonDisabled = false;
         });

        return $event.preventDefault();
    })  
});
```